# Aumentar el tiempo de session en hosting compartido

Tags: php, session

Como están amigos, a alguien más le pasó que el tiempo de vida de la variable $_SESSION no dura lo suficiente y cuando recargas la página vuelve a pedir que el usuario inicie sesión, alguien sabe como aumentar el tiempo de vida. Intenté en mi código PHP después de que los datos del usuario sean válidos

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', time() + (60*60*4));
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', time() + (60*60*4));
```

y en el php.ini del servidor he colocado lo siguiente:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 14400
session.cookie_lifetime = 14400
```

Pero aún así no funciona y el tiempo de vida sigue igual, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, encontraste la solución ?

Comment: nada amigo, hasta ahora no encuentro la solución, he probado muchas cosas y nada, tú la encontraste?

Answer (score 3):

Te comparto la solución que encontré después de tanto probar:

```
define('DURACION_SESION','7200'); //2 horas
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime",DURACION_SESION);
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",DURACION_SESION); 
ini_set("session.save_path","/tmp");
session_cache_expire(DURACION_SESION);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu aporte, muy bueno! En el sitio intentamos tener respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. La idea no es mostrar solamente un fragmento de código, sino además explicar por qué esto funcionaría. ¿Qué hace este código? En particular, qué hace `session.save_path`, en qué se diferencia `session_cache_expire()` del `session.cookie_lifetime` y por qué estás regenerando la sesión. Además, si la encontraste en algún lado, deberías agregar el enlace. En [answer] podrás leer algunos consejos. ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu respuesta agregando algo más de información?

Comment: gracias amigo, una pregunta: e tu php.ini como queda? has agregado algo más ahí?

Comment: el php.ini queda igual, el código lo vas a tener que poner cada vez que hagas una petición, ya que si no lo pones va a tomar siempre los valores del php.ini del server que es compartido para todas las páginas alojadas ahí, en ini_set("session.save_path","/tmp"); vas a tener que poner la ruta donde queres que se guarden tus sesiones. Luego me comentas si te funcionó.

Comment: La verdad es que tengo este problema desde hace más de un año y por fin encontré la solución, pero hubiera sido bueno en realidad que dieras un poco mas de información acerca de como funciona el código que nos compartiste porque tal vez haya trozos de código que mi sitio no necesite y que este allí haciendo nada. Pero por lo pronto te agradezco mucho por que me ayuste con este problema.