# ¿Cómo aumento tiempo de vida de variable de sesión PHP en hosting compartido?

Tags: php, session

soy nuevo aquí y mi pregunta la he visto bastante en foros pero no puedo dar solución en mi caso... Hace días compramos un hosting en godaddy y cargamos nuestra web en el cpanel que este brinda, han habido bastantes problemitas pero el que hasta ahora no podemos solucionar es el del tiempo de vida de las variables de sesión... veo que la solución que más se da es editando el php.ini, pero en mi caso no puedo ver ese archivo, lo busqué en la ruta que me dio php-info y no está, a lo mejor está oculto o no tengo acceso a él. Lo último que he intentado, pero sin respuesta aún son las siguientes líneas de código que encontré aquí mismo:

```
define('DURACION_SESION','7200'); //2 horas
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime",DURACION_SESION);
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",DURACION_SESION); 
ini_set("session.save_path","/tmp");
session_cache_expire(DURACION_SESION);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Bueno, para serles sincero tuve problemas con el session.save_path que no lo entendí muy bien; pegándolo así sólo me recargaba la misma página de inicio sin entrar a la sesión, pero quitando el parámetro de la ruta inició sesión al sistema, pero la sesión se sigue muriendo a la media hora.

Disculparán lo torpe que soy, pero les agradecería mucho si pueden ayudarme :(

Comment: Una alternativa que puedes utilizar el uso de una cookie con dos horas de vida que creas al iniciar la sesion, y la utilizas para actualizar la sesion.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. [Aquí se resolvió](https://es.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/PHP-Session-timing-out-too-soon/td-p/6044) estableciendo el valor de `memory_limit = 60M`. [Mira también aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140751/29967). Aunque debes saber que la info guardada en sesiones en hosting compartido no es segura [(ver aquí, también se da otra posible solución)](http://www.supernifty.org/blog/2008/04/19/php-sessions-on-shared-hosting-hack-3/). Si son datos sensibles piensa en algo así como una base de datos.